# Правильно написать srand()

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

Начну с того что ниже приведенный код работает

```
    srand(time(NULL));  // Или srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int num = rand() % 10;
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
```

вопрос стандарта, XCode высвечивает предупреждение:

```
    Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'
```

Если прописать так как в предупреждении:

```
    srand(time_t(NULL));    // Или srand(time_t(0));
```

то генерируются одни и те же псевдо рандомные числа.

Вопрос в том, как правильно по стандарту `C++ 11` написать данный код, что б давал рандом и не высвечивал предупреждения.

Comment: В C++11 есть целый набор средств для генерирования ПСЧ: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего так:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
```

Comment: Работает и не кидает предупреждения)

Answer (score 1):

В C++ правильно писать примерно так:

```
std::default_random_engine engine{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{0, 9};
auto gen = std::bind(distribution, engine);
```

Теперь для получения цифры просто вызываете:

```
gen()
```

Полный код:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine engine{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{0, 9};
    auto gen = std::bind(distribution, engine);

    std::cout << gen() << '\n' << gen() << '\n';
}
```